# Xcode 7 with iOS 9 device Error: device unavailable (Could not find a developer disk image)

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

After updating my iPad to iOS 9 public beta, I am getting an error while trying the run the app in my iPad. When I select the iPad as destination, it says "iPad (Unavailable) or Could not find developer disk image. How can I fix this? Any solution?

[image]

Comment: which version of Xcode 7 do you have

Comment: Xcode 7 GM seed (beta)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you are using the Xcode 7 GM build version **7A218**, the chances are that you accidentally downloaded iOS 9.1 (**13B5110e**) as opposed to the iOS 9 GM build (**13A340**). I did the same thing don't worry. They are too close to each other on the downloads page :0

You can check which version you have on your device by simply going to your device Settings > General > About > Version

All you have to do is [download](https://developer.apple.com/ios/download/) the correct iOS 9 GM build and go to iTunes. Click on your device. In the summary tab, <kbd>OPTION</kbd> + Right Click "Check for Update" and restore your device by navigating to the iOS 9 GM build finder location. **Note** by selecting "Check for Update" you will *not* lose any settings or data on your device. In other words, it is not a restore

However, if you are using Xcode 7.1 build version (**7B60**) iOS 9.1 is supported

Comment: My xcode build version is (7A218)
and ios 9 build version is (13B5110e)
what should i do?

If i downgrade my ios 9, will be everything ok? (i don't whether it is possible)

Comment: @GijoVarghese everything will be fine. Nothing will be erased.

Comment: i have updated itunes. I think its after that i couldn't run it on my device. So should i downgrade itunes?

Comment: How can i do that? Which one should i downgrade? itunes or ios?

Comment: @GijoVarghese read my answer. You downgrade your device because the GM Xcode does not support a beta os version. You have to download the GM iOS 9 build version 13A340 and install it as mentioned above.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. But I have got a problem. When i try to download ios 9 gm seed 13a340, it says "This download requires Apple Developer Program membership"

Comment: Then you need an Apple Developer Program Membership or sign in to your existing one @GijoVarghese

Comment: But i have installed ios 9 on my ipad without apple developer program before. I don't want to pay money (will do if necessary after learning).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89478/discussion-between-gijo-varghese-and-soulshined).

Comment: @GijoVarghese that's not really something anyone can fix. If Apple says you need an Apple Developer Program Membership then that's what you need. ( something unrelated to the question you posted)

Comment: but apple has given me betaprogram which i used to get the same ios software without paying. Nothing illegal

Comment: @GijoVarghese  We're getting into topics unrelated to this question. I answered your particular question in detail above. Apple let _anyone_ download iOS 9 public beta. Thats why it was all over the news. and that's why you were able to. If you want the GM build of iOS 9 you need a program membership. Thats all there is to it.

Comment: will this issue be solved when io9 stable is released?

Comment: Can you please answer answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659562/xcode-7-crash-when-trying-to-test-app-on-device

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and all I had to do was to update my XCode to 7.1. After that it worked. Your Xcode has to be updated to the latest version.

Comment: For anyone reading, I had to go to the App Store and manually install it to get it to upgrade.

Answer (score 7):

This is also encountered when trying to use Xcode 6.4 against an iOS 9.0.x device.  Here's how you can workaround it and get Xcode 6.4 to recognize your iOS 9.0.x devices:

1. Download Xcode 7.0.1:

http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.0.1/Xcode_7.0.1.dmg

2. Open Xcode_7.0.1.dmg and drag the Xcode.app to your desktop
3. Right-click, Show package contents, navigate into /Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
4. Copy the "9.0 (13A340)" directory to the existing DeviceSupport directory for your Xcode 6.4 install.  For example: ~/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
5. Restart Xcode 6.4 (if it was running), and your device running iOS 9.0.x should now show as a recognized device.

Comment: Xcode-beta never includes the latest "stable" release. You *always* need to copy over the DeviceSupport folder from Xcode. Guess what's inside? The Developer Disk image. True today for 9.1 as it was for 9.0.

Comment: Thank you for this!  :-) Much appreciated, worked like a charm! :-)

Comment: Work great, but watch out, Xcode.app weights more than 10GB.

Answer (score 5):

I solve this problem by just simple **xcode** restart.

Answer (score 4):

**Update Xcode**. If it not help:
go to

```
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
```

If you don't find there your device iOS version, you could try to copy last one and rename it to which one do you need, restart XCode and try to compile, it works for me.

Comment: Thanks , this helps to quickly resume working while downloading the new xcode

Comment: iamlcarus, you're welcome! I faced with this problem through iOS beta testing subscription, so I had iOS 9.1 beta but my stable version of Xcode didn't know this OS.

Answer (score 3):

Apple just released the new Xcode 7.1 which support iOS 9.1. Update Your Xcode and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced same issue

> **Could not find Developer Disk Image**

1) My `Xcode version was 7.0.1` and i updated my `iPhone to version 9.2`, then upon using Xcode my iPhone was shown in section of unavailable device. Just like in image below:

[image]

2) But then i somehow managed to select my iPhone by clicking at
Product -> Destination -> Unavailable Device

[image]

3) But that doesn't solved my problem and started showing

> **Could not find Developer Disk Image**

[image]

**Solution) Then finally i downloaded latest version of `Xcode version 9.2` from  https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ and everything worked fine for me.**

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that I just needed to open my phone and click "Trust Computer"

Answer (score 0):

I had XCode 7.0.1 installed + iOS 9.1 (13B143).

XCode had shown me "unsupported device" / "could not find developer disk image" in Devices windows until i updated my XCode to version 7.1. Everything works well now.

Answer (score 0):

I had already update to newest version Xcode (7.0.1) but still can't build on iPod touch 5 in iOS 9.1(13B143).After copy 9.1 (13B137) folder from my colleague to DeviceSupport folder in Xcode, it works! Not sure it would create some side effects.