# Xcode 7 crash when trying to test app on device

Tags: ios, xcode

I just updated Xcode to Xcode 7 and iOS 9 after the final release. When I tried to test My App on device Xcode crashed. To conform issue is not in my project created with Xcode 6, I created fresh project with Xcode 7 and tested even though Xcode crashed. I am using an iPhone 5.

Comment: What error do you get in you're Issue Navigator?

Answer (score 0):

Add this Entry in your .plist.

NSAppTransportSecurity
NSAllowsArbitraryLoads

[image]