# Getting message "Could not find Developer Disk Image" on Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to sideload my app onto my iPhone using Xcode 7.1, and it worked fine a few days ago, but now I'm updated to iOS 9.1, and now I'm getting an error "Could not find Developer Disk Image"

I made sure I'm using the latest version of Xcode, have restarted both the Mac and my iPhone, and done everything else I've been suggested, but nothing is working

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542036/xcode-7-with-ios-9-device-error-device-unavailable-could-not-find-a-developer/33343992#33343992